# Trying to make a class to define enemies

Tags: python, class

I don't really know how to word this other than: *does this work, and could I add more to it like the bush statement?*

```
class Enemy():

def __init__(self, name, HP, skills, attack, defense, loot, expget, flvrtxt):
    self.name = name
    self.HP = health
    self.skills = skills
    self.attack = attack
    self.defense = defense
    self.loot = loot
    self.expget = expget
    self.flvrtxt = text

bush = Enemy()
bush.name = "Bush"
bush.HP = 10
bush.skills = "none"
bush.attack = 0
bush.defense = 5
bush.loot = "A stick"
bush.expget = 50
bush.flvrtxt = "Just a bush, it cannot attack"
```

And by adding more, I mean can I basically copy paste the bush definitions, change the stats around and make a brand new enemy?
For example, could I add this?:

```
imp = Enemy():
imp.name = "Imp"
imp.HP = 50
imp.skills = "none"
imp.attack = 10
imp.defense = 10
imp.loot = "gold"
imp.expget = 150
imp.flvrtxt = "Cliche RPG enemy"
```

Comment: What is the problem you experienced when you add it?

Comment: I haven't implemented it _yet_, and wanted to make sure I got it done right. And figured I should check it first before I add it, have problems, and spend an hour wondering what went wrong

Comment: Your method should be named `__init__` (two underscores on each side).  Then you will be forced to pass all of those arguments to the `Enemy` constructor instead of assigning them after the object is created.

Comment: So, what would the code for what I'm trying to do look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I can think of two ways that you could go about this depending on what you are trying to achieve.

The way that you have your code structured now, you can create instances of the `Enemy` class, that are defined by their arguments. As @Patrick Haugh pointed out in the comments section, you could explicitly set all of the attributes of `Enemy` at construction if you update your method to be titled `__init__(self, name, HP, skills, attack, defense, loot, expget, flvrtxt)`:

```
class Enemy(object):

    def __init__(self, name, HP, skills, attack, defense, loot, expget, flvrtxt):
        self.name = name
        self.HP = HP
        self.skills = skills
        self.attack = attack
        self.defense = defense
        self.loot = loot
        self.expget = expget
        self.flvrtxt = flvrtext


bush = Enemy("Bush", 10, "none", 0, 5, "A Stick", 50, "Just a bush, it cannot attack")
imp = Enemy("Imp", 50, "none", 10, 10, "gold", 150, "Cliche RPG enemy")
```

Alternately, if you intend to instantiate specific types of `Bush`es and `Imp`s, you might want to create them as their own classes that sub-class the `Enemy` class but have their own default implementations for their associated fields:

```
class Bush(Enemy):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Bush, self).__init__("Bush", 10, "none", 0, 5, "A Stick", 50, "Just a bush, it cannot attack")

class Imp(Enemy):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Imp, self).__init__("Imp", 50, "none", 10, 10, "gold", 150, "Cliche RPG enemy")
```

This way would allow you to write code like the following, to instantiate a `Bush` that would come pre-poulated with all of the fields that you define for a `Bush` in its class:

```
bush = Bush();
```

Comment: the first one is exactly what I'm looking for! would it be possible to seperate the variables when typing them out? would be as simple as something like: "print(bush.Enemy(attack))"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about separating the variables; You can put them each on a new line when you are creating the `Bush` if you want though. If you wanted to print the attack value for a `Bush`, you would just call: `print (bush.attack)`. Because it's already an instance of `Enemy`, you don't need to explicitly reference the `Enemy` class.